# PhpStorm code completion and non physical file path for CSS and JavaScript

Tags: autocomplete, minify, phpstorm

Using minify, instead of including the individual CSS/JavaScript files directly, I have something like this in my HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/min/g=css8" type="text/css"/>
```

Autocomplete for CSS or JavaScript doesn't work in this html.

I tried looking for ways to be able to specify the individual files to PhpStorm to use in autocomplete, but could not find any option. Suggestions?

Comment: Well -- if file has no references to external (`<link...>`) or internal (`<style...>`) CSS, then PhpStorm will use all available CSS files for completion (I think there is hard coded limit of 20 global CSS files in v4, but maybe it was lifted since then). If you can remove such reference (e.g. adding it at run time -- using PHP or something like that) then it should help. Otherwise -- maybe actually create such `/min/` folder and have those files available there (it may only be created for development and ignored when uploading to production).

Comment: As for JavaScript -- have a look at **Settings | JavaScript | Libraries** - it should help (you can specify what files can be used and in what context).